# Copy file from FTP site to NFS share in Windows

Tags: ftp, window, nfs, unc, nfsclient

We have setup a NFS share(//191.232.xx.xxx/export/share) in windows and mapped to Z:. Now we need copy a file from FTP server to Z:. When we try following it works

```
Z:\>  (share NFS)
ftp server.com
ftp>get text.file
```

Above copies the file to Z:\text.file

But if I try try with UNC path, it don't work

```
ftp>get text.file //191.232.xx.xxx/export/share/text.file
```

I'm using windows native FTP and NFSCLIENT. The windows version is 2008 R2 sv1

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your registry and add an entry to disable the check on UNC paths.

HKEY_CURRENT_USER
      \Software
          \Microsoft
              \Command Processor

Add "DisableUNCCheck" (This is a 'DWORD (32-bits) value').
Set it to hexadecimal value "1".

Now restart your environment and have another go, this should do the trick!